# AJAX call skips sending some parameters or PHP loses some of them

Tags: php, javascript, html, parameters, header

I have a weird problem when sending parameters through an ajax call (jQuery1.4), but only with IE. I also tried it without jQuery, and wrote my own xmlhttp request, but I still get the same results.

When I send variables like this:

```
var1 = value1, var2 = value2, var3 = value3, var4 = value4
```

They are all passed to ajax query as a data property, and sent to the server. However, random parameters are missing in random places. For example, the PHP Server only receives:

`var1 = value1, var3 = value3, var4 = value4`

The passed values are URL encoded and contain normal short text strings. What could cause this kind of random skipping of variables?

Comment: it might help to see the code for the ajax call as well as an example URL that is generated by it

Comment: `Passed values are url encoded` - how are you doing that?

Comment: We really need to see code, both the JS side and the PHP side. It's unlikely anything is *randomly* going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an object? This way you don't have to worry with encoding params.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        var1 : 'value1',
        var2 : 'value2',
        var3 : 'value3',
        var4 : 'value4'
    }, 
    success: function(result) {
        alert('result');
    }
);
```